# Can multiple databases be configured in a single Spring Boot application

Tags: java, database, spring-boot

can I configure multiple Database configuration in spring boot project

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible !

You can define multiple data sources in your application YML like below

1)

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username: username
    password: password
    hikari:
      driver_class_name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver (or any other)
      connection_timeout: 30000
      maximum_pool_size: 5
    url: host:port/serviceName
```

2. 

```
someOtherKey
  datasource:
    username: username
    password: password
    hikari:
      driver_class_name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
      connection_timeout: 30000
      maximum_pool_size: 5
    url: driverName@host:port/serviceName
```

You can select which Datasource to pickup or provide via `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Bean`